# I am unable to get the currently taken image in the listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am unable to load the image in the listview, i have done like this in my `adapterclass`

```
    File imgFile = new  File(image.get(0));
    System.out.println(" ### imgFile" + imgFile);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

while here image is Array,but while giving the string path i am able to view the image to my whole `listview` but i want to to load the image for upcoming item which is to be loaded in the list view ,please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetView(...int position..){
File imgFile = new  File(image.get(position));
    System.out.println(" ### imgFile" + imgFile);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
..
// Set image here..
Holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,i am getting the image by using the array i have done like this    holder.place_images.setImageBitmap(image[position]); here my problem is i am getting the same after every 5 items in the listview but i want the last taken image in the listview